# Error al pasar datos a un diccionario

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo un pequeño lenguaje de programación en Python y me encuentro realizando las funciones, las almaceno en diccionarios para su posterior uso:

```py
Functions = {}

def Iniciar(Code:str):
    Code = Code.split('\n')
    for Line in Code:
        if Line.startswith("Function"):
            if Line.endswith(";"):
                FCode = Code[Code.index(Line)::]
                for tmp in FCode:
                    if tmp == "End;":
                        continue
                    else:
                        CollectForFunction(tmp)

def CollectForFunction(FunctionData:str):
        Frags = FunctionData.split("\n")
        for Frag in Frags:
            tmpN = ""
            tmpD = []
            if Frag.startswith("Function"):
                if Frag.endswith(";"):
                    PH = Frag.split("Function")
                    Name = PH[1].removeprefix(" ").removesuffix(" ")
                    tmpN = Name
                else: "Devolver Error"
            else:
                tmpD.append(Frag)
        Functions[tmpN] = [tmpD]

Código = "Function Hola;\nPrueba-1;\nPrueba-2;\nPrueba-3;\nEnd;"
Iniciar(Código)
print(Functions)
```

esto debería devolver `{'Hola':["Prueba-1","Prueba-2","Prueba-3",]}` pero devuelve esto:

````
{'Hola;': [[]], '': [['Prueba-3;']]}```
no tengo claro cual es el erro pero creo que tiene que ver con los ciclos
````

Comment: Huy no, esos `if` anidados no se ven muy bien. Por cierto cree un lenguaje de programación, puedes verlo en mi github https://github.com/nakato156/pseudocode-interpreter

Comment: @Christian compilaste tu lenguaje con Pyinstaller o Cython?

Comment: Con pyinstaller por ahora

Comment: @Christian sinceramente me parece muy bueno nada que ver con el mío no uso lexer solo divido todo y voy chequeando cosas (Sinceramente si no es posible arreglar las funciones me lo pensare de otra forma ya que trata de emular lenguajes como AppleSoft BASIC entre otros y me gusta bastante lo de poner marcadores estilo
10 PRINT "HOLA"
20 GOTO 10
)

Comment: Así comencé yo, tuve que rehacer todo varias veces. Ahí tienes el github para que puedas ir checando algunas cosas por si tienes dudas de como implementarlas., espero te sirva de algo.

Comment: de hecho este lenguaje lo he rehecho 3 veces ya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay un montón de problemas con el código. Para empezar, divides el código en líneas en `Iniciar`; luego en `CollectForFunction` vuelves tratas de dividir nuevamente en líneas un valor que ya es una sola línea. ¿Estarías tratando de dividir por ";"?

Es mejor replantear todo.

```
Functions = {}

def Iniciar(Code:str):
    Code = Code.split('\n')
    tmpN = None
    for Line in Code:
        tmpN = CollectForFunction(Line, tmpN)

def CollectForFunction(FunctionData:str, tmpN: str):
        if FunctionData.startswith("Function"):
            if FunctionData.endswith(";"):
                PH = FunctionData.split("Function")
                tmpN = PH[1].strip()[:-1]
                Functions[tmpN] = []
            else:
                raise ValueError("Devolver Error")
        elif FunctionData != "End;":
            Functions[tmpN].append(FunctionData[:-1])

        return tmpN

Código = "Function Hola;\nPrueba-1;\nPrueba-2;\nPrueba-3;\nEnd;"
Iniciar(Código)
print(Functions)
```

La función `iniciar` no necesita hacer nada más que dividir el código en líneas y pasarlas a `CollectForFunction`. Aquí el único detalle es acordarse del nombre de la función, lo que solucionamos entregandola en cada llamada y recibiendola de vuelta.

*Resultado*

```
{'Hola': ['Prueba-1', 'Prueba-2', 'Prueba-3']}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Gracias si funciona la verdad ahora que lo veo exagerada la cantidad de bucles for que use

Comment: como puedo hacer que si la palabra no es Función retorne al ciclo for?